# How to make Perl Generate Output files in a specific directory

Tags: perl, output, primes

Does anyone know how to use perl so output files can be generated automatically? I am running an input on the command line like this:

<<< nextprime(30659918)

30659947

But instead of the output "30659947" being in the command window, I am looking for a quick command that can generate an output file (such as Perl_command1.out in a given directory for example) with the characters "30659947" instead. Does anyone know how to do this? (Why I want to do this is so I do not have the command window racked up when I have larger 300k+ digit inputs)

The perl command I am using is:

perl -Mntheory=:all -E "say next_prime('30659918')

30659947

### or the script file: perlscript.pl

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';
use ntheory ":all";

say next_prime('30659918')
```

---

Comment: What is that line *<<< nextprime(30659918)* ? Is that a shell script? or some interactive program? How did you ran it?

Comment: [Output redirection?](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use output redirection.

```
perl -Mntheory=:all -E "say next_prime('30659918')" > Perl_command1.out
```

That will put the file in your current directory. But you can give it any kind of file path.

```
perl -Mntheory=:all -E "say next_prime('30659918')" > /some/other/directory/Perl_command1.out
```

The same thing works for a Perl program.

```
./perlscript.pl > Perl_command1.out
```

In general, I find that using I/O redirection like this is far more flexible than hard-coding filenames in your code.

I'm not sure where you got your `ntheory.pm` file from, but it's an accepted standard in Perl programming that modules like this have a name that starts with a capital letter. So `NTheory.pm` would be a better name.

Answer (score -1):

You can redirect output from the command line using operators. Another alternative is to redirect standard output to a file in perl script itself.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';
use ntheory ":all";

# open filehandle log.txt
open (my $LOG, '>>', 'log.txt');
# select new filehandle
select $LOG;

say next_prime('30659918');
```

Comment: Thanks for the script, can you please show me a command I can paste in the command line? Thanks

Comment: If you are on any of unix/linux systems, just copy paste the above lines into a script, with some name *printprime.pl*.  Then use following two command to turn it into executable script and run it.

    chmod +x printprime.pl
    ./printprime.pl

Comment: Whooever downvoted my post, I am assuming that it is because I didn't mention about command line redirection. I did it because, I was not sure about the expertise of the OP and on what platform he was working.